# rails custom integer validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm using form builder to build a form and am trying to validate a textfield input as an integer. The standard `:only_integer` flag for `is_numberically` validation won't work for me because I want to create a custom error message (because the database field name doesn't make for a great error display).

I've tried the below which doesn't seem to work, any ideas? Thanks!

```
if (days_final_refund - days_final_refund.to_i) >  0
    errors.add(:Balance_due, " - days before trip must be a whole number")
end
```

Comment: How does your model look? Is `days_final_refund` a float? Because otherwise, when assigned it will always be an int and will always return zero. You would probably want to check the value a sent in `params` before assigning it?

Comment: yes, it is an integer. i'm a bit of a rails noob. i've been setting all of my validation tests in the model file. i guess you're saying since it's at the model level it will have already converted from the entered float value to the integer value at the time of the validation test? how can i pull the param value at the model level? or should i somehow be doing this in the controller? thank you!

Comment: If you really want to warn the user, I would do it in the front-end/UI. Either by placing a hint that only integers are accepted and will be rounded off, by making a sure a user can only enter integers (e.g. a dropdown of possible values, or only acceptting digits), or giving a warning from js before submitting the form. That would be the easiest imho.